# Unit Testing the UpdateModel method within MVC 3.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-3

## Updated

I have recently modified a view to post to its controller a json object rather than a formcollection.

In order to get the unit test for this controller working we set the formvalue provider to a dictionary object to stop the UpdateModel method from throwing nre's.

The resulting unit test below however, simply does not feel like the right thing to be doing. Any insight into how to rework this would be greatly appreciated.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ThemeContent(content model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var content = _contentRepository.GetContent(model.id);
            if (content == null)
            {
                content = new content();
                UpdateModel(content);
                _contentRepository.Add(content);
                _contentRepository.Save();
            }
            else
            {
                UpdateModel(content);
                _contentRepository.Save();
            }

            return Json(new
            {
                redirectUrl = Url.Action("index", "success", new {id = content.id}),
                isRedirect = true
            });
        }

        string errorMessage = "{";

        foreach (var key in ModelState.Keys)
        {
            var error = ModelState[key].Errors.FirstOrDefault();
            if (error != null)
            {
                if (errorMessage != "{")
                {
                    errorMessage += ",";
                }
                errorMessage += (char) 34 + "#" + key + (char) 34 + ":" + (char) 34 + error.ErrorMessage + (char) 34;
            }
        }

        errorMessage += "}";

        return Json(new
        {
            Message = errorMessage,
            isRedirect = false
        });

    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not really clear why you're calling UpdateModel, when you already have all the values you need from model binding to the "model" object in the action parameter.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Brad. Silly oversight on our part that was greatly increasing the complexity of our tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated, as we were incorrectly using the updatemodel method.

```
       //setup
        var fakeContent = new content
        {
            address1 = "123 test street"
        };

        _controller.Url = new UrlHelper(
            new RequestContext(
                _controller.HttpContext, new RouteData()
                ),
            new RouteCollection()
            );

        //execute
        var result = _controller.ThemeContent(fakeContent) as JsonResult();

        //assert
        Assert.AreEqual("123 test street", _content.address1);
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't see the problem here. What don't you like?

Answer (score 0):

You need to mock the controller context in your unit test if the controller action your are trying to test relies on it. I would strongly recommend you looking at the [MVCContrib.TestHelper](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TestHelper) which would simplify the task of mocking this context and making your unit tests more elegant.

Comment: Thanks Darin. I have added a reference to the TestHelper and have been playing around with it this afternoon. Do you by any chance have an example of how to properly create a unit test when the controller under test is updating a model?

Comment: @Jesse, could you show the code you are trying to test? It will be more clear.

Comment: I have updated my question with the actionresult under test. Thanks for your time.